# Can't use a css selector to get data in python

Tags: python, web-crawler, selector

Hi I'd like to get movie titles from this [website](https://www.the-numbers.com/market/2019/top-grossing-movies):

[image]

```
url = "https://www.the-numbers.com/market/" + "2019" + "/top-grossing-movies"
raw = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})  
html = BeautifulSoup(raw.text, "html.parser")
movie_list = html.select("#page_filling_chart > table > tbody > tr > td > b > a")
for i in range(len(movie_list)):
    print(movie_list[i].text)
```

I got response 200 and have no problem crawling other information. but the problem is in the variable movie_list.

When I print(movie_list), it returns just empty list, which means I'm using the tag wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace:

```
movie_list = html.select("#page_filling_chart > table > tbody > tr > td > b > a")
```

With:

```
movie_list = html.select("#page_filling_chart table tr > td > b > a")
```

You get what I think you're looking for. The primary change here is replacing child-selectors (`parent > child`) with descendant selectors (`ancestor descendant`), which is a lot more forgiving with respect to what the intervening content looks like.

---

Update: this is interesting. Your choice of `BeautifulSoup` parser seems to lead to different behavior.

Compare:

```
>>> html = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html.parser')
>>> html.select('#page_filling_chart > table')
[]
```

With:

```
>>> html = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'lxml')
>>> html.select('#page_filling_chart > table')
[<table>
<tr><th>Rank</th><th>Movie</th><th>Release<br/>Date</th><th>Distributor</th><th>Genre</th><th>2019 Gross</th><th>Tickets Sold</th></tr>
<tr>
[...]
```

In fact, using the `lxml` parser you can *almost* use your original selector.  This works:

```
html.select("#page_filling_chart > table > tr > td > b > a"
```

After parsing, a `table` has no `tbody`.

After experimenting for a bit, you would have to rewrite your original query like this to get it to work with `html.parser`:

```
html.select("#page_filling_chart2 > p > p > p > p > p > table > tr > td > b > a")
```

It looks like `html.parser` doesn't synthesize closing `</p>` elements when they are missing from the source, so all the unclosed `<p>` tags result in a weird parsed document structure.

Comment: That worked perfectly! But I still wonder why my selector didn't work. As you can see in the uploaded picture, I thought I selected 679 movie titles correctly.

Comment: Aren't "#page_filling_chart table tr > td > b > a" and "#page_filling_chart > table > tbody > tr > td > b > a" directing the same tag?

Comment: They're not. `#page_filling_chart > table` says "find a `table` element that is a child of element id `#page_filling_chart`, whereas `#page_filling_chart table` says "find a `table` element that is a *descendant* of element id `#page_filling_chart`".

Comment: Ah, right I understood! It is different. May I ask just one more thing sir or ma'am..? Like, I thought I specified the tag by using child-selectors and didn't work. However, as you said, you used descendant selectors which forgives a lot more. I get how your code works But I don't know why my code using child-selectors!

Comment: I've updated the question with the result of some experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for this question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.the-numbers.com/market/" + "2019" + "/top-grossing-movies"
raw = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})  
html = BeautifulSoup(raw.text, "html.parser")
movie_table_rows = html.findAll("table")[0].findAll('tr')

movie_list = []
for tr in movie_table_rows[1:]:
    tds = tr.findAll('td')
    movie_list.append(tds[1].text) #Extract Movie Names

print(movie_list)
```

Basically, the way you are trying to extract the text is incorrect as selectors are different for each movie name anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```py
url = 'https://www.the-numbers.com/market/2019/top-grossing-movies'
raw = requests.get(url)  
html = BeautifulSoup(raw.text, "html.parser")
movie_list = html.select("table > tr > td > b > a")
for i in range(len(movie_list)):
    print(movie_list[i].text)
```